# How do I create a map between the observations in Column 1 to the observations in Column 2?

Tags: dictionary, sas, mapping, stata, one-to-one

My dataset consists of 2 columns - Host economy and Recipient economy - which specifies a number that is unique to each economy. For eg : Argentina is 1, Vietnam is 2, etc. I want to create a map from Host to Recepient economy, say map named Dij, which would give a value 0 if the code in host and Recepient is the same ( ie, say Argentina is both host as well as Recepient) and a value of 1 if the code is different for host and Recepient.

I can't figure out how to do this in Stata ( or SAS).

| Country code | Host | Recipient | Time | AUS:Australia | BEL: Belgium | CAN:Canada |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARG | 1 | 1 | 2000 | 0.044 | 0.087 | 0.072 |
| ARG | 1 | 1 | 2001 | 0.051 | 0.084 | 0.098 |
| ARG | 1 | 1 | 2002 | 0.062 | 0.064 | 0.067 |
| AUS | 2 | 2 | 2000 | 0 | 0.161 | 0.297 |
| AUS | 2 | 2 | 2001 | 0 | 0.131 | 0.324 |
| AUS | 2 | 2 | 2002 | 0 | 0.143 | 0.284 |
| BEL | 3 | 3 | 2000 | 0.338 | 0 | 0.284 |
| BEL | 3 | 3 | 2001 | 0.338 | 0 | 0.288 |
| BEL | 3 | 3 | 2002 | 0.338 | 0 | 0.281 |

This is a snapshot of my database. There are 40 countries that act as both host and recipient at some point in trade flow. I can't seem to create a matrix of the interaction between each country with all the other countries.

Any ideas?
And thank you in advance.

I tried creating a conditional variable, but that ofcourse took values 0 for all countries, as it had the same values for each country in host and Recepient column. I realize creating a variable is not the solution.

Comment: Huh?  Are you asking how to create an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix?  What does that have to do with SAS or STATA?  Please show an example of your input dataset and the desired output for that input.

Comment: Hey Tom,
I need to run a regression which would require me to pull data on the interaction of host with recipient, and I need those values to be 1 if they host is different from the recipient, and 0 if they're both the same. So you're right in saying that I need to integrate a matrix within that linear regression, and that has been where I'm facing a problem.

Comment: You just did a poor job of explaining what you are doing.  If you want to test if two variables are the same or not just compare them.  Sounds like you are not structuring data properly.  See the answer from Stu.  If you want to regress with these categorical variables use GLM and use a CLASS statement and GLM will automatically create the dummy binary variables to indicate the various levels (values) of the class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your data sounds like it looks like this:

```
data have;
    input host recipient;
    datalines;
1 2
3 4
4 4
5 5
6 7
;
run;
```

In SAS, you can use a shortcut to create a binary variable:
`var = (condition)`

This automatically outputs a 1 or 0 if a condition is true or false. In your case, you want to check if `host` is not equal to `recipient`.

```
data want;
    set have;
    flag = (host NE recipient);
run;
```

Output:

```
host    recipient   flag
1       2           1
3       4           1
4       4           0
5       5           0
6       7           1
```

Comment: Hi Stu,
Thank you so much for this. 
Given your example, I'm looking for a way to integrate all pairs of (host, recipient) in my model.
As in, I wish to pull data for set (host, recipient) = [ (1,2), (1,4), (1,5), (1,7),......(6,5),(6,7)]
I need to create integrate a matrix into my regression that would take a value 1 if host is not equal to recipient, and zero for entries like (4,4), ie, where the host country and recipient country are the same

Comment: This can be done in SAS. Can you post a small sample dataset of what you have? There are a few ways to go about this in base SAS depending on what your data looks like.

Comment: |Country code|Host |Recipient  |Time      |AUS: Australia       |BEL:Belgium|

|---------------|-----|------------|----------|-------------------|------|

|ARG        |1     |1          |2000       |0.04                |0.087| \\

|ARG        |1     |1               |2001       |0.01                |0.084| \\

|AUS        |2     |2          |2000       |0                        |0.161| \\

|AUS        |2     |2          |2001       |0                       |0.131| \\

|BEL                |3     |3          |2000       |0.3                   |0| \\

Comment: Hey Stu, I'm trying to create a dataset with 40 countries, each of which act as a host and a recipient at some point. The countries have been assigned a specific number (eg: Argentina is assigned 1) whether they act as a host or a recipient. Argentina will have interactions with all other 39 economies with a unique code each, hence giving us a set from (1,1) , ie, Argentina as both host as well as recipient, all the way upto (1,40), ie, Argentina as host and Vietnam as recipient. Similarly all other 39 countries will interact with the rest of the countries.

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is 
1) integrate this matrix into my regression
2) Get a value 0 for (1,1) and a value 1 for all orders from (1,2) till (1,40)

Comment: Can you post your data in your original post rather than the comments? It is hard to parse here

Comment: Yes, I've edited the post accordingly. I hope this would be clearer.